# Using contextlib with cython

Tags: python, opengl, cython

As part of transitioning my game engine's code to cython, I am porting my Vertex Buffer Object (Vbo) class. I use this Vbo class to send 3D model data to the GPU. The code (`vbo.pyx`) currently looks like this:

```
cimport gl
from enum import Enum
import contextlib

class VboTarget(Enum):
    ARRAY = gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
    INDEX = gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER

cdef class Vbo:
    cdef readonly gl.GLuint id_
    cdef readonly double[:] data
    cdef readonly int target

    def __init__(self, data=None, target=VboTarget.ARRAY):
        gl.glewInit()
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, &self.id_)
        self.target = target.value
        if data is not None:
            self.data = data

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def bind(self):
        gl.glBindBuffer(self.target, self.id_)
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            gl.glBindBuffer(self.target, 0)

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def update(self):#perform gpu update
        with self.bind():
            gl.glBufferData(self.target, self.data.nbytes, &self.data[0], gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
```

I would like to use `contextlib` as it would make ensuring that buffer binding and unbinding to the GPU would cleanly and automatically occur. The cython code compiles without error; however, when I import this cython module into my python code, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import vbo
  File "vbo.pyx", line 21, in init vbo (vbo.c:15766)
    @contextlib.contextmanager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 82, in contextmanager
    @wraps(func)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I am not really sure how to interpret this message. Can I use `contextlib` decorators with a `cdef class` and if so, how? Is `contextlib` even compatible with cython?

---

Update:
Here is an alternative version using `__enter__` and `__exit__` instead:

```
cimport gl
from enum import Enum
from cpython cimport array
import array

class VboTarget(Enum):
    ARRAY = gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
    INDEX = gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER

cdef class Vbo:
    cdef readonly gl.GLuint id_
    cdef readonly float[:] data
    cdef readonly int target

    def __init__(self, data=None, target=VboTarget.ARRAY):
        gl.glewInit()
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, &self.id_)
        self.target = target.value
        if data is not None:
            self.data = data

    def set_data(self, float[:] new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def update(self):#perform gpu update
        with self:
            gl.glBufferData(self.target, self.data.nbytes, &self.data[0], gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    def __enter__(self):
        gl.glBindBuffer(self.target, self.id_)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        gl.glBindBuffer(self.target, 0)
```

Comment: If you use a normal class in Cython instead of a `cdef` class, then `contextlib` is almost certainly compatible. I'm not yet sure if it can work with a `cdef` class - it looks complicated!

Comment: @DavidW If I use a normal class instead, then I would not be able to use any `cdef` extension types in my code, right? Vbos were one of the performance bottlenecks I had using just python, so I definitely want to type as many variables as possible. I can work around using `contextlib` using `__enter__` and `__exit__` instead with my `cdef` class, but then the user would be calling something like `with my_vbo:` rather than `with my_vbo.bind()`, which is not ideal.

Comment: Yes - a normal class doesn't have typed attributes. I think you could return a normal class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` attributes from `bind()` instead, which would keep the interface you want and the `cdef` class (and just require writing a little more code than using contextlib)

Comment: @DavidW That sounds like it would be perfect, but it is still unclear for me. I updated the question to show the alternative version I have with `__enter__` and `__exit__`. What would the `bind` function look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having tried a simplified version of your code it appears to work for me as is (Cython 0.25.1, Python 3.6.1):

```
import contextlib

cdef class Vbo:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def bind(self):
        self.do_something()
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            print("Finally")

    def do_something(self):
        print("something")
```

I don't think any of the changes for your more complicated example should actually affect this, but I don't have the `gl.pxd` so it's very hard to test. It might be worth making sure your Cython version is up to date (if you haven't already)...

**Edit:** I think the important difference might be Python 2.7 vs Python 3.6. Python 3.6 [has an `AttributeError` catch block](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/af5392f5c6f8014659e995840df6ee7b5017f743/Lib/functools.py#L61) while Python 2.7 [doesn't catch the error](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/787826c9316b03ac8a197078ec1cdf98fa840c5c/Lib/functools.py#L33). Therefore I don't think it's a change in Cython behaviour and so probably isn't really a bug.

---

As discussed in the comments, you can use a non-`cdef` `class` with `__enter__` and `__exit__` to get the same behaviour:

```
cdef class Vbo:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bind(self):
        class C:
            def __enter__(self2):
                # note that I can access "self" from the enclosing function
                # provided I rename the parameter passed to __enter__
                self.do_something() # gl.BindBuffer(self.target, self.id_) for you

            def __exit__(self2, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
                print("Done") # gl.glBindBuffer(self.target, 0)
        return C()

    def do_something(self):
        print("something")
```

---

So in summary - I can't reproduce your problem, but here's an alternative...

Comment: Thank you so much! `cython --version` showed I was using 0.25.2, although I am using python 2.7.12 with it. Your first sample gives the same error as in my question, interestingly enough. Your second solution, however, works perfectly for me with my `gl*` functions! I would not have thought about renaming `self` to `self2`.

Comment: The name `self` is only a convention in Python so you can always change it where necessary. It might be worth submitting a bug report to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/ for the `contextlib` problem since it appears to be an unhelpful regression.

Comment: That clears it up! I have now submitted a bug report there, so hopefully this will get resolved.

Comment: Well, they closed [my issue](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1750) off at the cython github page. They suggested adding `# cython: binding=True` to the top of my file, but that just led to a slightly different error message (`AttributeError: 'GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'next'`).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon See edit. I had a closer look at the Python standard library code and think this is actually a difference between Python 2.7 and 3.6. With that in mind I think it's unlikely to be fixed in Cython. (I don't know about the "no attribute 'next'")

Comment: Really appreciate the detective work! In that case, I will stick with the alternative you suggested at the bottom of your answer. This is just another reason that I should move on to python 3 I guess...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is actually a non-issue now with the latest Cython master (Cython version 0.26b0). The simplified version of the contextlib code described in @DavidW's answer works perfectly as long as the `binding=True` hint is applied at the top of your source file. The discussion of this Cython issue can be found [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1750).